# OpenCV error when using CvKNearest::find_nearest

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

> error C2664: 'float CvKNearest::find_nearest(const cv::Mat
>   &,int,cv::Mat &,cv::Mat &,cv::Mat &) const' : cannot convert argument
>   1 from 'cv::Mat' to 'const CvMat *'

```
                CV::Mat matROI = img_thr(validContoursWithData[i].boundingRect);           // get ROI image of bounding rect

                cv::Mat matROIResized;
                cv::resize(matROI, matROIResized, cv::Size(RESIZED_IMAGE_WIDTH, RESIZED_IMAGE_HEIGHT));     // resize image, this will be more consistent for recognition and storage

                cv::Mat matROIFloat;
                matROIResized.convertTo(matROIFloat, CV_32FC1);             // convert Mat to float, necessary for call to find_nearest
                //cvConvertScale(matROIResized, matROIFloat, 1, 0);
                cv::Mat matROIFlattenedFloat = matROIFloat.reshape(1, 1);

                cv::Mat matCurrentChar(0, 0, CV_32F);

                kNearest.find_nearest(matROIFlattenedFloat, 1, matCurrentChar);     // finally we can call find_nearest !!!

                float fltCurrentChar = (float)matCurrentChar.at<float>(0, 0);

                strFinalString = strFinalString + char(int(fltCurrentChar));        // append current char to full string
            }

            std::cout << "\n\n" << "numbers read = " << strFinalString << "\n\n";       // show the full string

            cv::imshow("matTestingNumbers", imgs[a]);     // show input image with green boxes drawn around found digits
```

Comment: error C2664: 'float CvKNearest::find_nearest(const cv::Mat &,int,cv::Mat &,cv::Mat &,cv::Mat &) const' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'cv::Mat' to 'const CvMat *'

Comment: I see an error in the first line. `CV` should be `cv`. Also where is `matCurrentChar` created?

Comment: cv in my code small and matcurrentchar created as you see in my code above                           cv::Mat matCurrentChar(0, 0, CV_32F);

Comment: Oh I see it, and where it is the kNearest object created? and where it is trained? Also, what are your includes?  And which version of opencv are you using? basically it is trying to use a function with old opencv structures... but it  could be due to how it was created

Comment: my train date declare kNearest.train(matTrainingImagesAsFlattenedFloats,  matClassificationInts);                                   and i use openCV 2.4.1.3                  #include "opencv2/opencv_modules.hpp"
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2\imgproc\imgproc_c.h>
#include "opencv2/ml/ml.hpp"    
#include "opencv2\features2d\features2d.hpp"
#include "opencv2\nonfree\nonfree.hpp"   @api55

Comment: Ok, can you edit your question and put a minimum compiling example, it is hard to follow from comments

Comment: can you sent to me your email and I will send all code for you, my mail is walidhamde66@gmail.com @api55